# Gson processes multiple json root elements

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I am using Gson to process a **huge** Json file contains multiple Json root elements.
Like:

```
{"a": 1}                
{"a": 2}        
{"a": 3}
```

There is **no separate comma** between those root elements.

I do know **it isn't a valid format**, and I have no control of the format of this file, but we could edit the file if necessary.

Currently my solution is read the file line by line and parse them one by one. But I think this is not every efficiency.

another solution is to edit the file and change all the root elements so that they are in an Json array. But again, I don't think this is a good approach. My file is huge.

Could someone help me with this? If there is other package could solve this problem. I am glad to switch to that.
Thanks

Comment: When you stated huge... are you reffering 1000 units? 1 thousand bits? 1 trillion terabytes? As far as I have used, up to 80 megabytes of JSON is usable in Android devices (with some slow down, but AsynkTasks do the job), and as far as 500 Megabytes in a Windows Server IIS ran with acceptable speed.

Comment: Hi @Bonatti Thanks for your reply. the file actually is 2GB. I need to do some pre-process on that data.

Comment: If there is a time window for you to process, I highly suggest breaking the data in smaller chunks, and consuming it in parts. An example would be break the file in smaller "outputs", that each contain a smaller grouping (such as 1~1000 elements), then running the JSON/Gson consumption of that data.

Comment: Thanks again. I am working on it. XD

Answer (score 0):

Write a `FilterInputStream` implementation that inserts a top-level array declaration and also inserts the commas.  You could then pass that to GSON to parse.

If the file really is huge and you can't hold the resulting large structure in memory, you could write the `FilterInputStream` to break the input into smaller but still valid top-level blocks.

The possibilities are endless here but I think a `FilterInputStream` of some sort will be one good solution.

Comment: Hi, Jim I think this approach is worth trying, thanks for your suggestion.